# npm package for signalr client not getting connected

Tags: javascript, npm, signalr

Hi we need to run signalr client on console, are there any npm packages available.
i've already tried this https://www.npmjs.com/package/signalr-client but it is not getting connected to server HUB.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/browse/keyword/signalr

Comment: do you use HTTP or HTTPS ??

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue under "Known Issues" title. "client.Proxy settings currently only work for HTTP and not HTTPS".

Alternatives

https://www.npmjs.com/package/signalrjs